# define a function to accept a specific list parameter

Tags: c#

I want to define a function with a parameter, that paramter must be a specific, defined in a list (for example)

i remember doing this years ago but my memory has failed me.

example

```
public void foo(specific choice list defined in my class){}
```

specific-list = x,y,z

consume it list this (i think)

```
foo(myclass.x)
```

Comment: Do you mean a generic? Like `Foo<T>(IList<T> lst)`?

Comment: are you asking about a varadic method? i.e. `public void foo(params int[] args)` ? or possibly `public void foo<T>(params T[] args)` ? (I'm inferring this from the `foo(myclass.x)`, where it *seems* from the `= x,y,z` that you mean `x` is a single item, not itself a list

Comment: Perhaps you are mixing up `enum` with `List<T>`?

Comment: @kaffekopp on re-reading, I suspect you're correct with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @kaffekopp's comment, it seems likely that you are talking about an `enum`, i.e.

```
public enum MyEnum // declare the enum type (optional: specify an underlying integer type)
{
    Apple,   // define the choices (note: enums are **not** strictly enforced;
    Pear,    // they are just named integers, and at runtime you can be surprised to find
    Bicycle, // that the actual value is 42, a value you never defined)
}
```

with (on `MyClass`):

```
public MyEnum SomeProp {get;set;} // define a property as being of that enum type
```

and:

```
public void Foo(MyEnum option) {...} // define a method that takes a parameter of the type
```

then either:

```
Foo(MyEnum.Bicycle); // passing a constant/literal
```

or:

```
MyClass obj = ...
Foo(obj.SomeProp); // passing an existing value from somewhere
```

Comment: perfect, my memory huh, enum was exactly it, many thanks to all